# Verifiy user existence after Windows Authentication to allow/block access

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, windows-authentication

I have an intranet application and I want to verify user existence after he login successfully into this browser default pop up:

[image]

But after that I want to check if the username exists into a database, and if it's not, I redirect to an error page or something like warning he can't access. And I can't reach that behavior, what should I use?

note: I still not have Authorization, I think later I'll have to implement.

In my `Startup.cs` I have:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
  //...
  app.UseAuthentication();
}
```

Edit:
In `Configure` I added that code after UseAuthentication and now it's working (feel this is horrible), is executing for each request. I'm controlling the execution to search the user by this key "Authentication" in the header of the request. This is the correct way to handle this?

```
app.Use(async (context, next) => {
                if (context.Request.Headers.Keys.Contains("Authorization"))
                {
                    var user = (WindowsIdentity)context.User.Identity;
                    var dbContext = context.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>();
                    var userName = context.User.Identity.Name;
                    var userInDb = dbContext.Users.SingleOrDefault(u => u.Login == userName && u.Active);

                    if (userInDb == null)
                        context.Response.Redirect("/noaccess.html");
                }

                await next.Invoke();
            });
```

Comment: Is the authentication working? (Does `context.User.Identity` have a valid value?)

Comment: What you ask is authorization, not authentication. Authentication means verifying the identity of the user - that was handled already by the browser and IIS or Kestrel. You're now asking how to authorize that already authenticated user to access some resource. One way to do this is through roles. When using Windows Authentication, a user's groups can act as roles. You may only have to specify the correct role to restrict access to a resource

Comment: @GabrielLuci Yes, there is a valid value

Comment: If you want to check membership in a database you need a database role provider that will check which roles (if any) are assigned to that Windows user

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I can't get everything you're saying, do you have some examples of this kind of logic? I'm struggling about roles too, It's hard to understand how this really works (authorization and authentication) and how to limit it. Because in my case just a few people will have the access to the application, but a lot of others can reach the authentication as the same

Comment: Check the docs, [Role-based Authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/roles?view=aspnetcore-7.0). The entire `Authorization` section is separate from `Authentication`. Authorization is the mechanism that tells the app what an account can or can't do. \

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos But since you're corrected, my question about authorization and not authentication makes me understand a little more how I have to proceed and search things

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos but what you say about what an account can or can't do, is referring to do something inside the application (when the user already logged in), right? But that's refer about verifying the user permission to access the whole application too?

Comment: @Dreidel Authentication is "I need to know who you are." Authorization is "I know who you are but I need to know if you're allowed to be here." ("Here" can be either the whole application, a specific section of the app, or just one page)